# What do these abbreviations in the Oxford German Dictionary mean?

Tags: abbreviation, dictionary

In the online Oxford German Dictionary, there are properties enumerated beneath it.

For example 'hatte' has:

> 1.u. 3. Pers.Sg.Prät. v

What do those abbreviations and symbols mean?

Comment: I appreciate this is a really dumb question, but short ngrams are hard to google for.

Comment: Welcome, @Rol! Every decent dictionary provides a guide to usage, where the abbreviations and acronyms that it uses are explained. I believe that your Oxford's does so, too, for the following edition does: https://books.google.de/books?id=NTPKLFGB2FkC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich it's the iOS german oxford dictionary app. It's not great software. Thanks for that link.

Comment: @choXer what does und mean in this context?

Comment: @Rol: *und* means, that the same form is used for first and third person singular. Is the quote complete? I would expect something like *von "haben"*?

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford German Dictionary must have a glossar and I'm sure, you will find all abbreviations there.

The verb *"hatte"* is:

- 1. Person Singular Indikativ Präteritum Aktiv des Verbs *»haben«*
- 3. Person Singular Indikativ Präteritum Aktiv des Verbs *»haben«*

Person = person
Singular = singular
Indikativ = indicative mood
Präteritum = a German tense similar (but not equal to) English past tense
Aktiv = active voice
Verb = verb  (German genitive case of *"das Verb"* is *"des Verbs"*
haben = to have

Comment: Thanks, the print version does (at least).